# Given a set of n points (x,y), is it possible to find the number of pairs of points with negative slopes between them in O(n logn) time?

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry, divide-and-conquer

Given a set of n points on a 2-d plane of the form `(x,y)`, the aim is to find the number of pairs of all points `(xi,yi)` and `(xj, yj)` such that the line joining the two points has a negative slope.

Assume that, no two `xi`'s have the same value. Assume all points lie within `[-100,100]` or some other range.

Comment: How is it possible to find all O(n^2) pairs of points in O(n logn) time?

Comment: Is it possible to find the count?

Comment: As you say O(n logn) is what you are looking for , I want to make sure one thing are they in sorted order in some way ??

Comment: @ashudeep21: btw divide and conquer is very good call asatag: this is the merge sort I propose. However, the problem is not that geometric...

Comment: @Boris: Yeah...I feel the same now. However I got stuck in this part of a larger problem, which seemed quite geometry intensive.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you are asking about is equivalent to finding the number of non-inversions in the array of the `y`s you will obtain when you sort the points in respect to `x`. You can afford this sorting - it is `O(n log n)`.

I remind you that inversion is `i` > `j` and `a[i]` < `a[j]`. The equivalence I am speaking of is easy to prove.

Imagine you have 6 points (4, 4), (2, 1), (6, 6), (3, 3), (5, 2), (1, 5). After you sort them in respect of `x` you obtain: (1, 5), (2, 1), (3, 3), (4, 4), (5, 2), (6, 6). You can see that the negative slopes are formed by <(2, 1), (3, 3)>, <(2, 1), (4, 4)>, <(2, 1), (5, 2)>, <(2, 1), (6, 6)> etc. All the pairs whose `y`s are not in inversion.

Number of inversions can be counted in `O(n log n)` using augmention of the merge sort algorithm: basically you only need to increase the counter of inversions every time you choose to add value of the right subarray (the one containing larger indices). You increase the number of inversions with the amount of still not processed values from the left subarray.

Here is example of the counting the number of inversions.

```
Initial array 5 1 3 4 2 6  inv := 0 // Total inversions: 6
merge step 1: <5 1 3> <4 2 6> inv = 0
merge step 2: <5> <1 3> | <4> <2 6> inv = 0
merge step 3: <5> [<1> <3>] | <4> [<2> <6>] inv = 0
merge step 4: <5> <1 3> | <4> <2 6> inv = 0 // both pairs were already sorted
merge step 5: <1 3 5> | <2 4 6> inv = 3 // we add one for 1, 3 and 2
merge step 6  <1 2 3 4 5 6> inv = 6 // we add 2 (3 and 5) for 2 and 1 for 4
```

After you find the number of inversions the number of non-inversions in the total number of pairs `(n * (n - 1)) / 2` minus the number of inversions `inv`.

In the example case this is: `6 * 5 / 2 - 6 = 9`.